# How do I move a window off screen in OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, display, multiple-monitors, off-screen

I'm using OSBuddy, if you don't know what that is, it's basically a java client for a game.

I'm also using a dual screen, iMac with an ASUS connected via VGA/thunderport that's to the left of my screen.

OSBuddy is basically a game, and I like playing it in the background. I only need the right half of the screen to show up. The problem is, I can drag it so it goes outside my screen on the right side on my iMac (which effectively leaves me with the useless left side), but on the left side on my ASUS, I can't drag it any further to the left outside my viewing screen. Is there any way I can force this? Is it a screen setting or something?

Answer (score 0):

As of the current version, I've figured it out. I'm using the Orion theme, which prevents it from being taken past the left side of the screen. Go to your settings, turn it off, and it'll revert to system titlebars and it'll work.